# HTTP Live Streaming iOS restriction

Tags: ios, iphone, http-live-streaming

I need to implement real-time video streaming from a security camera to an app over cellular. My concern is the following restriction:

> Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes
>   must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 64 kbps HTTP Live
>   stream

Is this referring to streaming FROM an app or TO an app (my case)? I'd love to use HLS but the 30s latency just doesn't cut it.

I know this is not a valid argument, but similar apps like Dropcam have made it to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming TO an App, i.e the App is downloading the video.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5):

> Warning: iOS apps submitted for distribution in the App Store must
>   conform to these requirements.
>
> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video
>   exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute
>   period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming. (Progressive
>   download may be used for smaller clips.)
>
> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are
>   required to provide at least one stream at 64 Kbps or lower bandwidth
>   (the low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only or audio with a still
>   image).
>
> These requirements apply to iOS apps submitted for distribution in the
>   App Store for use on Apple products. Non-compliant apps may be
>   rejected or removed, at the discretion of Apple.